# Convert String To XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-namespaces, for-xml

How to convert the below string to XML,

```
SET @string = '<Field>
<Field Name="'+@Cname+'">
<DataField>'+@Cname+'</DataField>
<rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
</Field>'
```

I tried `SET @xmlstring = CONVERT(XML,@string)`  but it displays below error
Msg 9459, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
XML parsing: line 4, character 13, undeclared prefix

Comment: because that's not valid XML. you're using the alias `rd:` which you haven't declared in the xml anywhere.

Comment: I just treat whole thing as string bro the single quotes on beginning and ending

Comment: But it doesn't know what the rd alias is. Also, you have mismatched closing tags. You have Field nested inside Field but only one of them is closed.

Comment: The `XML` type can store XML fragments as well as whole documents, but those fragments still need to be valid on their own. If you're not planning on using any of the XML methods to process the XML, you may as well store it as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh no! Never create XML via string concatenation! Just imagine, your variable comes with a value like `this -> value` or `Tim, Tom & Fred`... This might work perfectly, pass all tests and break after rollout with undefined errors.

Always use SQL-Servers support to create XML:

```
DECLARE @cname VARCHAR(100)='Some Name';

DECLARE @xml XML=
(
    SELECT  @cname AS [Field/@Name]
           ,@cname AS [DataField]
           ,'System.String' AS [TypeName]
    FOR XML PATH('Field')
);
SELECT @xml;
```

The result

```
<Field>
  <Field Name="Some Name" />
  <DataField>Some Name</DataField>
  <TypeName>System.String</TypeName>
</Field>
```

### And here with the namespace:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('Some.namespace.url' AS rd)
SELECT @xml=
( 
    SELECT  @cname AS [Field/@Name]
            ,@cname AS [DataField]
            ,'System.String' AS [rd:TypeName]
    FOR XML PATH('Field')
);
SELECT @xml
```

The result

```
<Field xmlns:rd="Some.namespace.url">
  <Field Name="Some Name" />
  <DataField>Some Name</DataField>
  <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
</Field>
```

Comment: Is there any tutorial for better understanding.Can you please Share?

Comment: @SrinivasanRajasekaran Start to read [the official docu about `FOR XML PATH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-path-mode-with-for-xml)

Answer (score 3):

Your xml need formatted correctly.

try to close tag Field with prop Name using '/' and take out prefix rd in TypeName.

```
SET @string = '<Field>
<Field Name="'+@Cname+'" />
<DataField>'+@Cname+'</DataField>
<TypeName>System.String</TypeName>
</Field>'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/8282/0

Comment: What about the alias (`rd`) the OP had on `Typename`?

Comment: For use rd prefix, it need be declared in first node as example xmlns:rd="namespace". This is used for specify the content about the prefix.

Comment: No, you should never create XML on string base... This is absolutely dangerous...

Comment: This depends the context of model that database, because the support of type xml in sql server started on sql server 2005. Sometimes it just to need convert for xml type.

Comment: @DiegoMoreira Uhm... well... You might add *valid for SQL Server below 2005* to your answer :-) We have 2018 now, I do not think/hope, that the majority uses v2000... At least you should add `REPLACE`s for `<, > and &`...

Comment: Is valid remember that when started the web services applications, don`t had support to xml type in sql server. Was very common save the xml data as string in database. This can still have reflexes nowadays. Now, @SrinivasanRajasekaran 's question is about conversion between types string and xml, no about create a xml.